# Setting Image picker sourceType so that only pictures and no video can be selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want users to be able to use a camera but not have the option of taking a video.  As it stands, both photo and video controls show in the bottom left corner of the view when camera is launched by user.  Below are my launchCamera and imagePickerController methods.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.challengePic.image = self.image;
if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
    self.challengePic.image = self.image;

    }

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (IBAction)launchCamera:(id)sender {
if (self.image == nil && [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}

}

- (IBAction)launchAlbum:(id)sender {
if (self.image == nil && [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}

}
```

Is there any way of setting the Image picker sourceType so that only pictures and no video can be selected?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

Don't include this line:

```
self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];
```

From the [UIImagePickerController class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes):

> By default, this property is set to the single value kUTTypeImage,
>   which designates the still camera interface when capturing media, and
>   specifies that only still images should be displayed in the media
>   picker when browsing saved media. To designate the movie capture
>   interface, or to indicate that only movies should be displayed when
>   browsing saved media, use the kUTTypeMovie identifier….

Answer (score 13):

If you only want to select images, don't set the `mediaTypes` property to all possible media types for the given source.

By default, the image picker will only show images from the photo library.

But your setting of `mediaTypes` is overriding this default and allowing videos as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to select images or videos, you can use a code like this.

```swift
self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
```

or

```swift
self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public. movie"]
```